# WSGIPath does not exist for my Flask app on AWS EBS with CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, knowledge-repo

I am trying to deploy [Airbnb's open source Knowledge Scaling Repository Application](https://github.com/airbnb/knowledge-repo) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using CodePipeline.  My pipeline is failing with an error: **Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist**.  I have configured my Pipeline through the console to look to /knowledge_repo/app/deploy/flask.py for the WSGI.

I see [AWS EB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) that seems to expect an application.py file for Flask apps, which does not exist in this repo.

What is the appropriate file path for the WSGI file for this app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to your EB enviroment > Configuration > Software > Modify and change WSGIPath.

[image]